# where i store html, css, imag, js in servlet by android application project

Tags: android

i use jetty great servlet in android application project, not dynamic web project . I don't know where i store html, css, imag, js  and how to call it  on this project. Someone can help me

Comment: Can you be more specific or clear? It's hard to understand what your problem is.